# Error Handling in opencv gpu

Tags: opencv, exception, error-handling, gpu

How to handle opencv gpu exceptions? Is there any specific set of error code api for opencvgpu exception handling?
I tried searching a lot but I only got 1 error code i.e. CV_GpuNotSupported.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm assuming that you know that CV_GpuNotSupported is NOT how OpenCV handles GPU exceptions, and in fact, it handles error when you try to call gpu methods without compiling OpenCV with `-DHAVE_CUDA` or `-DHAVE_OPENCL`, the way OpenCV (I also assume the newest OpenCV released version, 2.4.5) handles error codes, is defined in these files:

For methods that use NVIDIA CUDA:

> https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.5/modules/gpu/src/error.cpp
>
> https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.5/modules/gpu/src/precomp.hpp

For methods that use OpenCL:

> https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.5/modules/ocl/src/error.cpp
>
> https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.5/modules/ocl/src/precomp.hpp

As for the API, you can use `cv::gpu::error` or `cv::ocl::error`. Or to get the error string, `getErrorString` for cv::gpu and `getOpenCLErrorString`. And by the way for CUDA's error you have to specify whether it's an [NPP](https://developer.nvidia.com/npp), NCV, [cufft](https://developer.nvidia.com/cufft), or [cublas](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublas) error.